# How do I get the sign up/login popup after I deleted it?

Tags: bubble.io

When I first started my bubble project I deleted all the preset reusable elements like header, footer and sign up / login popup. Is there a way that I can get the sign up / login popup element back? I've included an image of what I'm talking about.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIVMP.png)

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic but effective solution: Copy it from another application and paste it